# If A == B, will that imply that [A isEqual:B] is true?

Tags: objective-c

I just found out a bug. Tracing the bug, I saw that this is violated when A (and hence B) is nil.

I just want to make sure I am not missing anything here.

Is the answer of the question true or do I just find an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return code from a message sent to `nil` will always be 0, which equates to `NO` or false. So the behaviour you observe is expected and correct, even if it may not seem exactly intuitive. Different `nil` objects aren't properly equal, since `nil` doesn't really have an identity.

Comment: Thanks I need the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-c you can send a message to a nil object ie [A isEqual:B] when A is nil.  But you can't expect a nil object to return a result!  I haven't yet found the Apple ref, but I suspect that the return value is either undefined or set to nil/false/0 itself.

Comment: Sending a message to `nil` can return a value, and is documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7. (I did not downvote though)

Comment: @MartinR I did suspect (and should have known) that a value would be returned, but the point I was trying to make was that no logic in the target class would/could have been executed.